# Rails 4: Net::ReadTimeout when calling ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

When I run my mailer in development mode, I get the following error:

```
Net::ReadTimeout in SchoolApplicationsController#create
```

Here is the controller method that is getting the timeout

```
  def create
    @school_application = SchoolApplication.new(school_application_params)
     @school_application.program_cost =    @school_application.calculate_cost_to_charge(params[:school_application][:program], params[:school_application][:duration])
    if @school_application.save

      NotificationsMailer.send_application(@school_application).deliver
      redirect_to application_path(@school_application.id)
    else  
      Rails.logger.debug(@school_application.errors.full_messages)
          @school_application.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        flash.now[:error] = msg
      end
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
```

I am positive the error is being caused by the `NotificationsMailer` call because when
I comment it out, I no longer get the error.

Here is my mailer, and the settings:

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "from@slf.net"
  default :to => "nayr@slf.net"

  def send_application(application)
    @application = application 
    mail(:subject => "New Application")
  end
end
```

Here is my `environments/development.rb` smtp settings:

```
Fls::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'secure3309.hostgator.com',
  port:                 465,
  domain:               'slf.net',
  ssl: true,
  user_name:            ENV['slf_username'],
  password:             ENV['slf_password'],
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
end
```

When I write `ENV['slf_username']` in the Rails console I get the right value. Same with the password. The username is in the format user@slf.net. Is that correct or is the right format just "user" and the domain is implied from `domain` parameter?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After reading this [post](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/639) I took another look at my smtp settings and added

```
tls: true
```

changed 
   `port: 465` to `port: '465'` as I noticed that most people write it as a string. Also Similarly changed the string `"plain"` to the symbol `:plain`

Comment: Looks like `tls: true` is the key. I don't believe the other changes matter. (Also note it is `tls`, not `tsl`.)

Comment: this is nowhere to be seen in the Rails docs!

Answer (score 8):

I faced the similar issue when i connect the smtp mail to qq mail(business mail).
I updated my settings by following the [post](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/639#issuecomment-29016055) as like below:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.exmail.qq.com',
port:                 '465',
domain:               'groobusiness.com',
user_name:            ENV['GMAIL_USER_NAME'],
password:             ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
authentication:       :plain,
enable_starttls_auto: true,
openssl_verify_mode:  'none',
ssl:                   true,
tls:                   true
}
```

And the issue got solved.
Hope it might be helpful for someone who is facing this issue.

Answer (score -2):

add following code in intitialize

```
require 'net/smtp'

module Net
  class SMTP
    def tls?
      true
    end
  end
end
```